# programmatically find containing object or prototype of given method in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given a random function `f`, can I do these in javascript code:

1. check if it's defined as a method
2. if yes to 1, check which object contains it, like `obj.f`
3. or, check which prototype contains it, like `obj.__proto__.f` or `objConstructor.prototype.f`

Comment: please add your question and your code.

Comment: @NinaScholz  I am just wondering "can such thing doable and if yes how" that's the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object hierarchy in javascript is a directed graph, where nodes are objects and arrows are the "references" relationship:

```
a = {}
a.bar = b
b.foo = c


(a) --refererences--> (b) --references--> (c)
```

There are no "backwards" arrows ("referenced by"), therefore, given an isolated object, you have to walk the whole graph to find out nodes which refer to it. To do that, you need some start node, which can be `global`/`window` for global objects, but for locals  there's no such thing. Therefore, this is only possible if you explicitly create such start node and make it refer to all objects in your program. For instance, you can have a function

```
let world = new Set();

function create(klass, ...args) {
   // @todo: garbage collection
   let obj = new klass(...args);
   world.add(obj);
   return obj;
```

and consequently use `create(MyClass)` instead of `new MyClass`. Then, given a function `f` you can start with `world` to drill the graph down to `f` to find out where it belongs to. Whether these complications are actually useful is up to you (hint: they are not).